# Wagner–Fischer algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming, edit-distance

I'm trying to understand the Wagner–Fischer algorithm for finding distance between to strings. I'm looking through  a pseudocode of it in the following link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm

```
int EditDistance(char s[1..m], char t[1..n])
   // For all i and j, d[i,j] will hold the Levenshtein distance between
   // the first i characters of s and the first j characters of t.
   // Note that d has (m+1)  x(n+1) values.
   let d be a 2-d array of int with dimensions [0..m, 0..n]

   for i in [0..m]
     d[i, 0] ← i // the distance of any first string to an empty second string
   for j in [0..n]
     d[0, j] ← j // the distance of any second string to an empty first string

   for j in [1..n]
     for i in [1..m]
       if s[i] = t[j] then  
         d[i, j] ← d[i-1, j-1]       // no operation required
       else
         d[i, j] ← minimum of
                    (
                      d[i-1, j] + 1,  // a deletion
                      d[i, j-1] + 1,  // an insertion
                      d[i-1, j-1] + 1 // a substitution
                    )

   return d[m,n]
```

Actually I get the algorithm's point and understand it intuitively, by it's not obvious for me why are **d[i-1, j] + 1, d[i, j-1] + 1 and d[i-1, j-1] + 1** considered as a **deletion, insertion and substitution**. It'd be great if someone explained the implementation nuances in a more detailed way.

Answer (score 11):

I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/stefanthaler/ccc3dca0f72f4186f742dbd83ca89739) which prints out the sequence of operations as well as the goal which each step is trying to solve, which should complement my explanation of the Fischer-Wagner algorithm.

To be able to understand the Fischer-Wagner algorithm you have to keep in mind that it is belongs to the family of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)  algorithms. This means that it will compute partial solutions to a bigger problem, store the partial solution and use the result of the partial computation for the next computation.

So what does this mean for the Fisher-Wagner algorithm? In this context this means that each element of the distance matrix d contains the best possible trace of operations to get you from your current string A to another string B. This explanation is still a little bit abstract, so let me explain what I mean by that by walking you through an example.

Lets assume you want to calculate the Levensthein distance of the two strings "*ABV*" and "*FV*" using the Fischer-Wagner algorithm. Then your distance matrix will look like this:

```
+-----+---+---+---+---+
|     |j->| 0 | 1 | 2 |
+-----+---+---+---+---+
|   i |   | # | F | V |
+-----+---+---+---+---+
|   0 | # |   |   |   |
|   1 | A |   |   |   |
|   2 | B |   |   |   |
|   3 | C |   |   |   |
+-----+---+---+---+---+
```

The first row/column of this table name the indices of the distance matrix, the second name the characters of the strings. '#' is the empty string (i.e. a string with zero length).

Each element of this distance matrix marks a subproblems that you want to solve. For example, the entry [i=0, j=2] contains the shortest distance from arriving from an empty string "" to "*FV*" the entry [i=2, j=1] contains the shortest distance for the problem "*AB*" => "*F*".

Let's fast forward the algorithm to the subproblem [i=2, j=2], i.e. how to get from "*AB*" to "*FV*". In this case, the distance matrix looks like this.

```
+-----+---+---+---+---+
|     |j->| 0 | 1 | 2 |
+-----+---+---+---+---+
|   i |   | # | F | V |
+-----+---+---+---+---+
|   0 | # | 0 | 1 | 2 |
|   1 | A | 1 | 1 | 2 |
|   2 | B | 2 | 2 |   |
|   3 | C | 3 | 3 |   |
+-----+---+---+---+---+
```

"*B*" and "*V*" are not equal, which means we need to perform one of the following three operations to make them equal:

1. delete "*B*". We take the cost of the cell above d[i=1, j=2], because we know that this cell is the cheapest sequence of operations that gets us from "*A*" => "*FV*". However, our problem is getting from "*AB*" => "*FV*", not from "*A*" => "*FV*. We do know that we can replace "*A*" by "*FV*" by applying the operations of cell d[i=1, j=2] (we solved this subproblem earlier), which leaves us with a string "*FVB*" for the cost of 2. We then deleted the "*B*"  ("*FVB*" => "*FV*") and we are done. The cost of this operation is 2+1.
2. insert "*V*". Similar as delete "*B*", only we take the value to the left d[i=2, j=1] because we know it is the cheapest sequence of operations to get from "*AB*"=>"*F*". Since our problem is to get from "*AB*"=>"*FV*", we only need to add the cost of inserting "*V*" and we are done.
3. substitute "*B*" with "*V*". Similar to the previous cases. We know that d[i=1, j=1] contains the cheapest sequence of operations to change "*A*"=>"*F*". Applying this operation changes our problem changes to "*FB*"=>"*FV*", which can be solve by substituting "*B*" with "*F*".

After considering these 3 options, we pick the cheapest one, which is substituting "*B*" by "*F*" (1+1).

After solving all subproblems in that fashion, the output will produce the final result, which is the minimal edit distance from "*ABC*
 => "*FV*".

Comment: Very good answer! I wonder is the asterisk marks in `we can replace "A*"* by "FV" by` just typos? They are quite confusing.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist it was indeed a typo and I corrected it, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Note the string which is imagined to be kept at columns is constant and we need to find the edit distance of the string kept at rows . See this for example
[image]

Here we are trying to compute Edit distance of AVERY !
So now, the substructure
DP[i][j]=DP[i-1][j-1] (if G[j]==A[i])

NOTE: G stands for GARVEY and A for AVERY

because If we can solve Edit Distance of G[j-1] and A[i-1] in k operations we can solve G[j] and A[i] operations ( No operation needed for last character)

Other wise

DP[i][j]= minimum of following

DP[i-1][j]+1  (See we can only delete from the Row String (whose EDIT distance is to be calculated !) DP[i-1][j] represents the string G[1...j] and A[1...i-1]!  See the character A[i] deleted??)

DP[i][j-1]+1 (See this is not a deletion!! What we do is add a character at i+1 th posiition ! And hence it is equal to G[j] (We can add any character))

DP[i-1][j-1]+1 (I guess this is easy now the i th and j th character weren't same so what we did was change the A[i] th character into G[j]th)

Feel free to ask doubts :)

Comment: Hey I guess I got the first point (deletion) A[1...i-1] claims that A[i] has been deleted. But the insertion and substitution remain non intuitive. Say "What we do is add a character at i+1 th posiition" is not obvious.

Comment: Let the string be A[1...i] where A[i] does not equal to B[j] (Here A is the string whose Edit Distance is to be calculated !) As A[i]!= B[j] what we do is insert a character just after i th position which is equal to B[j], So, the edit distance will be 1 plus Edit distance of A[1....i] & B[1...j-1] (j-1 because we have fixed it by adding another character)



Substitution is as simple as that A[1....i] and B[1....j] , here A[i]!= B[j] what we can do is we can substitute A[i] such that it is  equal to B[j]... and then our edit distance will be 1+edit distance of A[1....i-1] & B[1...j-1]

Comment: But if A[i]!= B[j] why we insert a character just after i th position which is equal to B[j]

Comment: We are looking at the edit distance of A[1...i] and B[1...j] . Now inserting some other letter will cause nothing good ! Why? Just because we will have to delete it or add another letter which is not optimal for minimum edit dostance... Now dynamic programming is a careful brute force so we try all the possibilities deletion, insertion and replacement. Thats why we try each deletion,insertion and replacement!

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a very clear article](https://zxi.mytechroad.com/blog/dynamic-programming/leetcode-72-edit-distance/).
The memoized recursive version may be easier to understand, the difference is that the subproblems are evaluated in a different order.